# How do I add programs to a sabyon live USB?

Tags: software-installation, gentoo, live-usb, sabayon

How do I install software on a [sabayon](http://www.sabayon.org/) live USB and have that software persist after rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, typically, but these will be lost when you do a reboot if the medium is read only, such as a CD and/or DVD. I've done this from time to time when needing to recover passwords from NTLM systems and not having an actual LiveCD handy that includes the recovery software.

So in a pinch I've booted using an Ubuntu LiveCD and then installed the necessary software, and recovered the NTLM passwords from a Windows partition.

With a USB flash drive that includes a live installation you're likely going to find that you still cannot install software either. Sometimes there is a reserved area where you can park addon applications which will then get pulled into the Live system upon bootup, but it's generally recommended that you install the Live distro instead on the removable media if you intend to customize it in any fashion.

I realize you're working with Sabayon, but I did find this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd) which shows a farily detailed and painful looking process one would need to go through if you wanted to customize the packages of an actual Live distro. Similar steps would likely be required for Sabayon as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding packages to a live USB and having those applications persist after rebooting is typically achieved by rebuilding the .iso image.

Here are specific instructions for achieving USB persistence. 
https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Bootable_USB_with_persistance

This tool appears to be able to create a persistent Sabayon live USB.

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/persistence/68-persistent-do-not-do

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/persistence